# What is the name of this Slovenian (maybe Czechoslovakian) science fiction book?

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a book which has a bunch of space explorers visiting different planets. The book follows the idea that space is round and that by flying in one direction, eventually a ship can come back exactly where it was before. There is one particular planet that the explorers stop at and there are grasshoppers. One of the men step on and kill one of them before flying off of the planet again. After flying though space for a long time, they land on the same planet where a giant grasshopper (possibly the mom) steps on the same man that stepped on the first grasshopper showing that they were intelligent to some degree.

I don't know much more about this book other than it was written in a Slavic language most likely Slovenian or Czechoslovakian. Does anyone know the book or some authors who may have written it?